# How do I add null value in Time of day type on google charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I want to send null of Timeofday for represent empty value into Google charts but it throw error to me.

> Cannot read property 'length' of null

How do I add null value of Timeofday type? This is my code.

```javascript
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Day');
    data.addColumn('timeofday', 'A');
    data.addColumn('timeofday', 'B');

    data.addRows([
        [new Date(2016, 06, 1), [02, 51, 56], [02, 51, 56]],
        [new Date(2016, 06, 2), [02, 51, 56], [02, 51, 56]],
        [new Date(2016, 06, 3), null, [02, 51, 56]],
        [new Date(2016, 06, 4), [02, 51, 56], [02, 51, 56]],
    ]);

    var options = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Test',
            subtitle: 'test'
        },
        width: 900,
        height: 500
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

I expect my chart to be this, But in Timeofday type.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

using a *Core Chart* vs. a *Material Chart* works...

you can use the following option to get the look and feel close to a *Material Chart*

`theme: 'material'`

see following example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Day');
    data.addColumn('timeofday', 'A');
    data.addColumn('timeofday', 'B');

    data.addRows([
      [new Date(2016, 06, 1), [02, 51, 56], [02, 52, 56]],
      [new Date(2016, 06, 2), [02, 51, 56], [02, 52, 56]],
      [new Date(2016, 06, 3), null,         [02, 52, 56]],
      [new Date(2016, 06, 4), [02, 51, 56], [02, 52, 56]],
      [new Date(2016, 06, 5), [02, 51, 56], [02, 52, 56]],
    ]);

    var options = {
      chart: {
        title: 'Test',
        subtitle: 'test'
      },
      theme: 'material',
      width: 900,
      height: 500
    };

    var chartCore = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart_core'));
    chartCore.draw(data, options);

    var chartMatl = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
    chartMatl.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
  },
  packages: ['corechart', 'line']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="linechart_core"></div>
<div id="linechart_material"></div>
```

Comment: tried versions `'41'` thru `'45'` vs. `'current'` to get _Material_ to work, no luck...